# Ajax call JS + PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Chrome console error:
POST http://******************** 500 (Internal Server Error)

JS

```
$.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url:"ajax.php",
                    data: {
                        x: x,
                        y: y
                    },
                    success:function(data){...}
                 });
```

PHP

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$link = mysql_connect("*******", "*******", "******");
mysql_select_db("******") or die ("no database");


$name = $_POST['x'];
$score = $_POST['y'];

// Get the current date
$current_date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO hungry_bird (date_played, name, score)
               VALUES('$current_date ', '$name', '$score')";

$results = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());

mysql_close($link);


?>
```

Any idea what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Check the console and see what it says, right click inspect element console in chrome.

Comment: A 500 error in PHP indicates that you need to check your web server's error log for full details. Better still, _always_ when developing and testing code, add to the top of your highest included file `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  The error will come through the ajax response.

Comment: I see you are using d-m-Y. If that is a MySQL DATETIME column (as it should be), the correct insert format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`, but that would not cause a 500 error.  The code itself is also vulnerable to SQL injection in `$name,score`. Please read through [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) At a minimum, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on those two variables, but if you are in any position to change the approach, now is the time to switch to `prepare()/execute()` with PDO (detailed in the link)

Comment: ... because the `mysql_*()` functions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.

Comment: open your console and tap on network tab you will find the request there  there will be your php error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("*******", "*******", "******");
mysqli_select_db($link, "******") or die ("no database");
$name = $_POST['x'];
$score = $_POST['y'];
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO hungry_bird (date_played, name, score)
               VALUES('CURDATE()', '$name', '$score')";
$results = mysqli_query($link, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_close($link);
```